# Constexpr class function definition linking error

Tags: c++

Function is declared in hpp file like this:

```
class StringProcessor
{
    static constexpr const char* string_process(const char* initial_string, std::size_t string_length, const char* key, std::size_t key_length);
};
```

And defined in cpp like this:

```
constexpr const char* StringProcessor:: string_process(const char* initial_string, std::size_t string_length, const char* key, std::size_t key_length)
{
     ...
}
```

How do I call it, because following line throws `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "StringProcessor::string_process(char const*, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from: _main in main.cpp.o` error:

```
std::cout << StringProcessor::string_process("Test", 4, "Test", 4) << std::endl;
```

Comment: `constexpr` requires definition where it is used...

Comment: Offtopic: consider replace `const char*` and `size_t` pair with `std::string_view`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`constexpr` functions are implicitly `inline` and therefore need to be defined in every translation unit where they are used. That usually means that the definition should go into a header shared between the translation units using the function.

Also, in order for `constexpr` to be of any use, the function needs to be defined before its potential use in a constant expression. Therefore it usually only really makes sense to define it directly on the first declaration, i.e. here in the `class` definition in the header.

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly declare it? Maybe something like explicit instantiating like for templates?

Comment: @THE_CHOODICK The whole point of `constexpr` is to tell the compiler that the function can be (at least sometimes) evaluated at compile-time. To be able to do that the compiler must know the definition of the function before it is used. So no.